# Rename uploaded file with timestamp not working

Tags: php

I am sending email with attachment through phpmailer,but i want to rename the file before uploading it into directory.I have tried attaching timestamp before the extension but to the dismay its not working.

```
    $currentdir = getcwd();

    // for image uploading
$target_dir = "$currentdir/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        echo "<br>". $target_file;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where is the timestamp?

Comment: Yup i added it after the $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"].But it didnt worked so removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try it like this:

```
    <?php

        $currentDir     = getcwd();
        $targetDir      = "$currentDir/uploads/";
        $fileName       = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType  = pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // NEW FILENAME BASED ON THE CURRENT TIMESTAMP
        // THE NEW FILENAME IS PREFIXED WITH AN UNDERSCORE(_) CHARACTER IN THIS CASE...
        $timeBasedName  = $targetDir . "_" . time() . ".{$imageFileType}";
        $uploadOk       = 0;


        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $timeBasedName)){
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) .
                " has been uploaded as \"{$timeBasedName}\".";
            echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            echo "<br>". $target_file;
            $uploadOk   = 1;
        }
```

Comment: @abhisheksingh   What Error(s) are you getting? ***Do you have appropriate Permissions on the  `/uploads` Folder and even the ones above it?***

Comment: @abhisheksingh   The Post has been updated with those changes in Place...

Comment: Yup,the file is getting uploaded no problems in that just i wanted to rename it before it gets uploaded to avoid redundancy

Comment: @abhisheksingh    The Line: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $timeBasedName)` should take care of that.... `$timeBasedName` contains the Full Path to the Uploads Directory plus the name of the File was derived from TimeStamp with a **_** as a Prefix....